# How do I check whether the random expression answer equals the numbers inputted by the user?

Tags: android

Basically what i trying to do is display a random expression on the screen and check if the answer of the random expression is equal to the answer inputted by the user, if its correct that display "CORRECT" on the screen when # is pressed once and bring the next random expression up when # is pressed once again..

- i can get it to display the random expression on the screen but can't get to check if the answer is correct or not and display "correct"

i have beem researching on this for like 3 whole days but got to the following code:

```
package org.example.question;

import java.util.Random;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int fnum0;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //variable for different questions
    int snum0,fnum1, snum1,fnum2, snum2,fnum3, snum3,
    fnum4, snum4,fnum5, snum5,fnum6, snum6,fnum7, snum7,
    fnum8, snum8,fnum9, snum9, answer;


    //variable and type declaration for buttons and text
Button keyOne;
Button keyTwo;
Button keyThree;
Button keyFour;
Button keyFive;
Button keySix;
Button keySeven;
Button keyEight;
Button keyNine;
Button keyDel;
Button keyZero;
Button keyHash;
Button keySubtract;
TextView display;
TextView display1;
int answer0;
TextView correct;
String str;
int q;


private int click;






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        //display text on screen

        display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Guess);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
        correct= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CORRECT);

        int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));

        //generate random expression with random operators and display "?" if the answer is one digit or"??" if the answer is greater than       
         fnum0 = (int)((double) (Math.random() * 10));
         snum0 = (int)((double) (Math.random() * 10));

         if(operation == 0)
          str  = fnum0+  "+"  +  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??"); 

        else if(operation == 1) 
           str = fnum0 +  "-"  +  snum0+  "=" + ((fnum0-snum0<10)? "?" : "??");   
        else if(operation == 2)  
           str = fnum0 +  "*"  +  snum0+  "=" +  ((fnum0*snum0<10)? "?" : "??");   
        else  
           str = fnum0 +  "/"  +  snum0+  "=" +  ((fnum0/snum0<10)? "?" : "??");  
        display.setText(str);
        answer0=fnum0+snum0;


        ///Code for correct and incorrect

        //assigning names to each keypad
        keyOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        keyTwo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        keyThree= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        keyFour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        keyFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
        keySix= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        keySeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        keyEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        keyNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        keyZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_0);
        keySubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        keyHash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
        keyDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

        //setting button to produce an event when each button is pressed
        keyOne.setOnClickListener(this);     keyTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     keyThree.setOnClickListener(this); 
        keyFour.setOnClickListener(this);    keyFive.setOnClickListener(this);     keySix.setOnClickListener(this);     
        keySeven.setOnClickListener(this);    keyEight.setOnClickListener(this);  keyNine.setOnClickListener(this);    
        keySubtract.setOnClickListener(this);   keyHash.setOnClickListener(this);  keyDel.setOnClickListener(this);


}

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        switch(arg0.getId()){   

        //what happens when hash button is pressed

        case R.id.keypad_hash:


            if(click==1 && "CORRECT".equals(display.getText().toString()))
            {
                correct.setText("CORRECT");
                click=2;
            }
            if(click == 2)
            {
                display.setText(str);
            }
            else if("CORRECT".equals(display.getText().toString()))
            {
                fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
                snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
            }
            else;

            fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));        

           //generates random number between 0 to 9 with random operators for first and sceond number

            break;







        case R.id.keypad_1:

            String str1 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str1.replace("?", "1"));  
        break; 






        case R.id.keypad_2:
            String str2 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str2.replace("?", "2"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_3:
            String str3 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str3.replace("?", "3"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_4:
            String str4 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str4.replace("?", "4"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_5:
            String str5 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str5.replace("?", "5"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_6:
            String str6 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str6.replace("?", "6"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_7:
            String str7 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str7.replace("?", "7"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_8:
            String str8 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str8.replace("?", "8"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_9:
            String str9 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str9.replace("?", "9"));
            break;

        case R.id.delete:

            break;

        case R.id.keypad_0:
            String str0 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str0.replace("?", "0"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_subtract:
            display.setText("-");
            break;
        }
        }

    public void requestFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating things. I would set up a simple interface, that includes an Editable to get the answer, a button to say that you've inputed the answer you wanted to, and in the onClick() method for the button, check the Editable text and see if it is the correct answer.

Comment: so do i store the answer that the user inputs in a variable?

Comment: No need really, although you could. That's up to you really.

Comment: i dont understand about EDITABLE, i googled it and it shows me a method, do i have to create a seperate method for it?

Comment: @ZainAfzal: Sorry, that was supposed to be EditText... Anyways, check the [SDK out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html).

Comment: Is there any easier what to compare the users answer to randon expressions answer without using the Editext?